# code to copy itself raises an error to fast to see before the window closes, why could this be?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a program for a friend. It is meant to duplicate itself and then run the duplicate, then the duplicate does the same, and on and on (in each duplicate, it runs for some amount of iterations).

I am using the `os.system` and the `xcopy` commands to copy it, but it throws up an error and I don't know what it is (it is so fast it is invisible), so I cannot tell why it is not working.

Here is the code:

```
def copySelf():
    for i in range(1):
        os.system('xcopy duplotest.py .\\')
copySelf()
```

I will increase the amount of iterations later, but for testing, I set the `range` equal to `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to copy the file in such a way that it would overwrite itself.
I ran your command from the command line on my Desktop using a file called temp.py.
Running your command on my file:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop>xcopy temp.py .\
```

The result was the following:

```
C:temp.py
File cannot be copied onto itself
0 File(s) copied
```

I hope this solves your problem.

As a debugging suggestion for this kind of problem maybe consider using `>` to write the output of the command to a text file that you can read even if the command line closes too fast as you said.

Comment: JSON Brody, I was wondering if there was a way to bypass this:<br>`Does duplotest0.py specify a file name
or directory name on the target`<br>
`(F = file, D = directory)?`<br>
I do not want the thing to have to confirm this, as I need to have this be automated. Thanks